# How do I convert a variant array into an Excel defined name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variant array:

```
vNames(1) = "Joe"
vNames(2) = "Sarah"
vNames(3) = "Lisa"
vNames(4) = "Erik"
```

How can I set this array to an Excel defined name? I want to save it as an Excel defined name in order to use it in data validation later.

Comment: Not possible as specified - an Excel *Defined Name* is an alias for a *Range*, not for any general data structure.

Comment: Yes, you will have to copy the values to a sheet and then define a name for the range.

Comment: @Pieter - An excel defined name is an alias for a formula, not a Range.

Comment: @Pieter, thats not correct, try defining a name with a refersto of =(1+2)*4 and you will see that its is not returning a Range, its returning the result of a formula which may or may not be a range.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: It's a good day when  learn something new and interesting; thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim vNames(1 To 4, 1 To 1) As Variant
    vNames(1, 1) = "Joe"
    vNames(2, 1) = "Sarah"
    vNames(3, 1) = "Lisa"
    vNames(4, 1) = "Erik"
    Range("A1:A4").Value = vNames
    Range("A1:A4").Name = "aRose"
End Sub
```

and then later:

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a defined name that refersto an array of constants rather than a range

={"Joe","Sarah","Lisa","Erik"}

But I don't think data validation will accept such a name.